# Software for saving and viewing historical pdf annotations

Tags: pdf, archiving, annotation

There are some documents that I read, annotate, and highlight often. My current practice is to make a copy of an original 'template' `.pdf` file, and then add annotations and save it with the date (i.e. `file_name_mm_dd_yyyy.pdf`, or something similar).

It would be very useful if there were a utility that could have some kind of annotation history and I could browse through past annotations on an individual file or even look at a conglomeration of multiple annotations (i.e. an overlay of highlights over time where the most highlighted passages would show up more strongly).

Do people have recommendations of tools or a workflow that could approximate this kind of functionality?

It would be even better if the tools/workflow were non-proprietary, or at least exportable in a way to enable long-term archival/preservation of this data.

Comment: Using cpdf (disclaimer, which I wrote), from https://community.coherentpdf.com/ you can use `cpdf -list-annotations-json in.pdf > out.json` to save out the annotations to a JSON file. Then, at any point in the future, you can use `cpdf -remove-annotations in.pdf AND -set-annotations-json out.json -o out.pdf` to add any given set of saved annotations back to the PDF for viewing. You may need the latest beta for this to work properly - contact me via the website if necessary.